# Can not connect to RDS Proxy for Aurora Postgresql cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I create an AWS RDS Proxy to an Amazon Aurora Postgresql database cluster.

If I open a shell into a Bastion host in the same VPC, I can connect to the database, but can't connect to the proxy:

```
# proxy
nc -zv test123.proxy-xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 5432
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )

Ncat: Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx failed: Connection timed out.
```

```
# database endpoint
nc -zv xxxrdsdatabasecluster.cluster-xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 3307

Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to x.x.x.x:3307.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.01 seconds.
```

The database works fine, I can open a pgshell to it, connect apps to it. Why can't I connect to the proxy?

I've followed these troubleshooting steps:

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.troubleshooting.html#rds-proxy-verifying

Everything looks fine. All instances show up with TargetHealth.State = "AVAILABLE".

I created the proxy using the web interface. I chose default options and specified a secret with the login credentials in the appropriate format. I'm not sure what else to try.

Do I have to setup IAM permissions? Do I have to grant special IAM connect privileges to the proxy? What can I try?